# My iOS Mvvmcross app not able access and render a drop-down list of Recipients (AllRecipients) that I have in my database from the Core project

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, sqlite-net-extensions, mvxbind

New to xamarin MvvmCross and struggling with some issues. Appreciate for any help.

**My questions relates to:**

> I. My iOS app not being able access and render a drop-down list of
>   Recipients (AllRecipients) that I have in my database from the Core
>   project.
>
> On my SendView, I can render a list of items from hard coded
>   repositories that I have, like Country, City, Service that the user
>   can select from. But unfortunately I cannot render the list of
>   AllRecipients which are dynamically created.

My Droid project doesn't have those issues. I can render a list of items from both hard coded repositories that I have, like Country, City, Service as well as from the dynamically created data(i.e AllRecipients) and that the user
can select from for further action (say send money). I am using a SQLite-net extension.

[This is the screenshot for AllRecipients that is not rendering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhB6f.png)

[This also a screenshot for other hard coded items its rendering from a different repository.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZmom.png)

1. SendViewModel

   ```
   public Recipient SelectedRecipient

   {
       get { return _selectedRecipient; }
       set
       {
           if (_selectedRecipient != value)
           {
               _selectedRecipient = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedRecipient);
           }
       }
   }

   public Service SelectedService
   {
       get { return _selectedService; }
       set
       {
           if (_selectedService != value)
           {
               _selectedService = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedService);
           }
       }
   }
   public Country SelectedCountry
   {
       get { return _selectedCountry; }
       set
       {
           if (_selectedCountry != value)
           {
               _selectedCountry = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedCountry);
           }
       }
   }
   public City SelectedCity
   {
       get { return _selectedCity; }
       set
       {
           if (_selectedCity != value)
           {
               _selectedCity = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedCity);
           }
       }
   }
   public string SendContentTitle
   {
       get { return _sendContentTitle; }
       set
       {
           _sendContentTitle = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => SendContentTitle);
       }
   }
   public string SendContentBody
   {
       get { return _sendContentBody; }
       set
       {
           _sendContentBody = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => SendContentBody);
       }
   }
   public ObservableCollection<Beneficiary> Beneficiaries
   {
       get { return _beneficiaries; }
       set
       {
           _beneficiaries = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => Beneficiaries);
       }
   }
   public ObservableCollection<Service> Services
   {
       get { return _services; }
       set
       {
           _services = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => Services);
       }
   }
   public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries
   {
       get { return _countries; }
       set
       {
           _countries = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => Countries);
       }
   }
   public ObservableCollection<City> Cities
   {
       get { return _cities; }
       set
       {
           _cities = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => Cities);
       }
   }
   public ObservableCollection<string> PossibleTimes
   {
       get { return _possibleTimes; }
       set
       {
           _possibleTimes = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => PossibleTimes);
       }
   }

   public DateTime SelectedDate
   {
       get { return _selectedDate; }
       set
       {
           _selectedDate = value;
           RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedDate);
       }
   }
   public object RecipientName { get; private set; }
   public string CountryName { get; private set; }
   public string CityName { get; private set; }
   public string ServiceName { get; private set; }

   Send _send;


   public IMvxCommand SaveSend
   {
       get
       {
           return new MvxCommand(() =>
           {

               _send.RecipientId = SelectedRecipient.RecipientId;
               _send.CountryId = SelectedCountry.CountryId;
               _send.CityId = SelectedCity.CityId;
               _send.ServiceId = SelectedService.ServiceId;
               _send.RecipientName = SelectedRecipient.RecipientName;
               _send.CountryName = SelectedCountry.CountryName;
               _send.CityName = SelectedCity.CityName;
               _send.ServiceName = SelectedService.ServiceName;
               Mvx.Resolve<SendRepository>().CreateSend(_send).Wait();
            Close(this);
           });
       }
   }
   public IMvxCommand SendCommand
   {
       get
       {
           return new MvxCommand(() =>
               ShowViewModel<SearchResultViewModel>(new SendParameters
               {
                   RecipientId = SelectedRecipient.RecipientId,
                   CountryId = SelectedCountry.CountryId,
                   CityId = SelectedCity.CityId,
                   ServiceId = SelectedService.ServiceId,
                   //RemittanceDate = SelectedDate
               }));
       }
   }

   public SendViewModel(IMvxMessenger messenger,
       IBeneficiaryDataService beneficiaryDataService,
       ICountryDataService countryDatasService,
       IServiceDataService serviceDatasService,

       ICityDataService cityDataService,
       IConnectionService connectionService,
       IDialogService dialogService) : base(messenger)
   {
       _beneficiaryDataService = beneficiaryDataService;
       _countryDataService = countryDatasService;
       _serviceDataService = serviceDatasService;

       _cityDataService = cityDataService;
       _connectionService = connectio`enter code here`nService;
       _dialogService = dialogService;

   }
   public override async void Start()
   {
       base.Start();

       await ReloadDataAsync();
   }


   protected override async Task InitializeAsync()
   {
       await base.InitializeAsync();

       if (_connectionService.CheckOnline())
       {
           await LoadCities();
           await LoadCountries();
           await LoadServices();

       }
       else
       {
           await _dialogService.ShowAlertAsync("No internet available",);

       }
   }

   internal async Task LoadCities()
   {
       Cities = (await_cityDataService.GetAllCities())
                     .ToObservableCollection();
   }

   internal async Task LoadCountries()
   {
       Countries = (await _countryDataService.GetAllCountries())
                      .ToObservableCollection();
   }
   internal async Task LoadServices()
   {
       Services = (await _serviceDataService.GetAllServices())
                      .ToObservableCollection();
   }

   public ICommand NavBack
   {
       get
       {
           return new MvxCommand(() => Close(this));
       }
   }

   public void Init()
   {

   }
   public void Init(Send send = null)
   {
       Task<List<Recipient>> result =
       Mvx.Resolve<RecipientRepository>().GetAllRecipients();
       result.Wait();
       AllRecipients = result.Result;

      string  sendContentTitle = 
      Mvx.Resolve<RecipientRepository>().GetSendContentTitle().ToString();

      string sendContentBody =
      Mvx.Resolve<RecipientRepository>().GetSendContentBody().ToString();

       SendContentTitle = sendContentTitle;
       SendContentBody = sendContentBody;
       _send = send == null ? new Send() : send;
       RaiseAllPropertiesChanged();
   }
   ```
2. SendView

   ```
   private UIPickerView _recipientTextPicker;
   private UIPickerView _countryTextPicker;
   private UIPickerView _cityTextPicker;
   private UIPickerView _serviceTextPicker;

   private const int TextFieldMargin = 10;
   public static readonly int ArrowWidth = 14;

   protected SendViewModel SendViewModel => ViewModel as SendViewModel;

   public SendView(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
   {
   }

   protected override void CreateBindings()
   {
       base.CreateBindings();

       var set = this.CreateBindingSet<SendView, SendViewModel>();

       set.Bind(sendButton).To(vm => vm.SaveSend);
       CreateRecipientBinding(set);
       CreateCountryBinding(set);
       CreateCityBinding(set);
       CreateServiceBinding(set);


       set.Apply();

       UpdateUi();
       AddPickerToTextField(recipientTextField, _recipientTextPicker);       
       AddPickerToTextField(countryTextField, _countryTextPicker);
       AddPickerToTextField(cityTextField, _cityTextPicker);
       AddPickerToTextField(serviceTextField, _serviceTextPicker);

   }

   private void AddPickerToTextField(UITextField textField, UIPickerView pickerView)
   {
       textField.TintColor = UIColor.Clear;

       var leftPaddingView = new UIView(
           new CGRect(0, 0, TextFieldMargin, textField.Frame.Height));
       textField.LeftView = leftPaddingView;
       textField.LeftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always;

       var arrowImageView = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0,
           ArrowWidth + TextFieldMargin, textField.Frame.Height))
       {
           Image = UIImage.FromBundle("arrow-down.png"),
           ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.Left
       };

       textField.RightView = arrowImageView;
       textField.RightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.UnlessEditing;

       textField.InputView = pickerView;

       var toolbar = CreateToolbar();

       textField.InputAccessoryView = toolbar;

       textField.Layer.BorderColor = SaafiColors.BorderColor.CGColor;
       textField.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
       textField.Layer.CornerRadius = 4;
   }
   private void CreateRecipientBinding(MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet<SendView, SendViewModel> set)
   {
       set.Bind(recipientTextField).To(vm => vm.SelectedRecipient).OneWay();
       _recipientTextPicker = new UIPickerView
       {
           ShowSelectionIndicator = true
       };

       var recipientPickerViewModel = new MvxPickerViewModel(_recipientTextPicker);
       _recipientTextPicker.Model = recipientPickerViewModel;
       set.Bind(recipientPickerViewModel).For(p => p.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.AllRecipients).OneWay();
       set.Bind(recipientPickerViewModel).For(p => p.SelectedItem).To(vm => vm.SelectedRecipient).OneWayToSource();
   }


   private void CreateCountryBinding(MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet<SendView, SendViewModel> set)
   {
       set.Bind(countryTextField).To(vm => vm.SelectedCountry).OneWay();
       _countryTextPicker = new UIPickerView
       {
           ShowSelectionIndicator = true
       };

       var countryPickerViewModel = new MvxPickerViewModel(_countryTextPicker);
       _countryTextPicker.Model = countryPickerViewModel;
       set.Bind(countryPickerViewModel).For(p => p.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Countries).OneWay();
       set.Bind(countryPickerViewModel).For(p => p.SelectedItem).To(vm => vm.SelectedCountry).OneWayToSource();
   }
   private void CreateCityBinding(MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet<SendView, SendViewModel> set)
   {
       set.Bind(cityTextField).To(vm => vm.SelectedCity).OneWay();
       _cityTextPicker = new UIPickerView
       {
           ShowSelectionIndicator = true
       };

       var cityPickerViewModel = new MvxPickerViewModel(_cityTextPicker);
       _cityTextPicker.Model = cityPickerViewModel;
       set.Bind(cityPickerViewModel).For(p => p.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Cities).OneWay();
       set.Bind(cityPickerViewModel).For(p => p.SelectedItem).To(vm => vm.SelectedCity).OneWayToSource();
   }
   private void CreateServiceBinding(MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet<SendView, SendViewModel> set)
   {
       set.Bind(serviceTextField).To(vm => vm.SelectedService).OneWay();
       _serviceTextPicker = new UIPickerView
       {
           ShowSelectionIndicator = true
       };

       var servicePickerViewModel = new MvxPickerViewModel(_serviceTextPicker);
       _serviceTextPicker.Model = servicePickerViewModel;
       set.Bind(servicePickerViewModel).For(p => p.ItemsSource).To(vm => vm.Services).OneWay();
       set.Bind(servicePickerViewModel).For(p => p.SelectedItem).To(vm => vm.SelectedService).OneWayToSource();
   }


   private UIToolbar CreateToolbar()
   {
       var toolbar = new UIToolbar(new CGRect(0, 0, 320, 44));

       var done = new UIBarButtonItem("OK", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Bordered, (sender, e) =>
       {
           cityTextField.ResignFirstResponder();
           countryTextField.ResignFirstResponder();
           serviceTextField.ResignFirstResponder();
           recipientTextField.ResignFirstResponder();

       })
       {
           TintColor = SaafiColors.AccentColor
       };

       toolbar.SetItems(new[] { done }, false);

       return toolbar;
   }

   protected void UpdateUi()
   {
       View.AddGestureRecognizer(new UITapGestureRecognizer(() =>
       {
           recipientTextField.ResignFirstResponder();
           countryTextField.ResignFirstResponder();
           cityTextField.ResignFirstResponder();
           serviceTextField.ResignFirstResponder();

       }));
   }
   ```
3. LinkerIncludePlease

   ```
   public class LinkerIncludePlease
   {
   public void Include(UITextField textField)
   {
       textField.Text = textField.Text + "";
   }
   public void Include(UIBarButtonItem button)
   {
     button.Clicked += (sender, e) => { button.Title = button.Title + "";};
   }
   public void Include(UIButton uiButton)
   {
       uiButton.TouchUpInside += (s, e) =>                          
       uiButton.SetTitle(uiButton.Title(UIControlState.Normal), 
       UIControlState.Normal);
   }
   public void Include(IMvxCommand command)
   {
       command.CanExecuteChanged += (s, e) => 
      { if (command.CanExecute(null)) command.Execute(null); };
   }
   }
   ```

D. SetUp

```
    protected override IMvxApplication CreateApp()

    {
        var dbConn = FileAccessHelper.GetLocalFilePath("saafimaster.db3");
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton(new RecipientRepository(dbConn));
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton(new TransferRepository(dbConn));
        Mvx.RegisterSingleton(new SendRepository(dbConn));
        return new Core.App();
    }
```

Comment: Does `Recipient` implement `INotifiyPropertyChanged` interface ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iOS Mvvmcross app not rendering a drop-down list from db and getting bind errors when saving data to the db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247410/ios-mvvmcross-app-not-rendering-a-drop-down-list-from-db-and-getting-bind-errors)

Comment: Thanks @Pilatus. I only have plain properties in my `Recipient` class. I am doing all my bindings in `RecipientViewModel`

Comment: @Cheesebaron do you have an idea of what the issue is? Would appreciate a little help.

Comment: @Cheesebaron Removed the possible  duplicate post. Can you please update your comment in lieu of this. Thanks